# Independence of Poisson distributed random variables

Tags: probability, poisson-distribution, covariance

Let $V, W, Z$ be independent Poisson distributed random variables. We now set $X:=V+W$ and $Y:=V+Z$.

- Compute $Cov(X,Y)$.
- Are $X$ and $Y$ independent?
- Find the probability mass function (PMF) of $X$ and $Y$.

I already have difficulties solving the first task. Covariance is defined as $Cov(X,Y)=E[XY]-E[X]E[Y]$. I already know that $E[X]=\lambda + \mu$ and $E[Y]=\lambda + \nu$. How do I get $E[XY]$? Do I have to solve:
$\frac{(\lambda + \mu)^{k}}{k!}\cdot e^{-\lambda + \mu} \cdot \frac{(\lambda + \nu)^{l}}{l!}\cdot e^{-\lambda + \nu}$? If so, could somebody please give me a hint?

Best,
Jolle

Comment: Yes, they are. I edited my post. Sorry!

Comment: Well if X and Y are independent, then clearly we have $Cov(X,Y)=0$. So lets find out. $E[XY]=E[(V+W)(V+Z)]=E[V^2+VW+VZ+Z^2]$. Now since you just mentioned V, W and Z are independent we are done since this just becomes $E[V^2]+E[V]E[W]+E[V]E[Z]+E[W]E[Z]$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Use the Bilinearity of Covariance: For any random variables, $A,B,C,D$, we have ... $$\mathsf{Cov}(A+B,C+D)=\mathsf{Cov}(A,C)+\mathsf{Cov}(A,D)+\mathsf{Cov}(B,C)+\mathsf{Cov}(B,D)$$And, of course, you should know that the covariance of independent random variables is zero, so...

---

As for (c)

$\mathsf P(X=x,Y=y)=\sum_{v=0}^{\min\{x,y\}}\mathsf P(V=v)\mathsf P(W=x-v)\mathsf P(Z=y-v)$

Comment: Thanks a lot! Since $Cov(X,Y)=Var(V)=E[V^{2}]-(E[V])^{2}=\lambda^{2}-\lambda^{2}=0$, I already know that $X$ and $Y$ are independent, right?

To find their PMF, is it useful to rearrange $P(X=x=v+w | Y=y=v+z)$? As an example, if X and Z=X+Y, I can write $P(X=x | Z=z)=P(X=x | Y=z-x)$.

Comment: @Jolle $\mathsf {Var}(V)=\lambda$ if $V\sim\mathcal{Pois}(\lambda)$

Comment: Ok, so $X$ and $Y$ are not independent because $\lambda > 0$. How do I start with calculating the PMF of these random variables? The idea I had above only works in case of independent random variables, as far as I know.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: covariance is bilinear,so:

$$\mathsf{Cov}(X,Y)=\mathsf{Cov}(V+W,V+Z)=\mathsf{Cov}(V,V)+\mathsf{Cov}(V,Z)+\mathsf{Cov}(W,V)+\mathsf{Cov}(W,Z)=$$$$\mathsf{Var}(V)+0+0+0=\mathsf{Var}(V)$$

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Comment: You are welcome.